# Wordpress single-(posttype).php fehler

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type (projects) and a page-projects.php. Both of them work. I add a single-projects.php and if I go to a single post there comes the 404 page. In the backend if I add a new project-post I can see the preview. But if I save the post and go again to the preview there is the 404 page.

How can I fix this problem?

Ps. I think if i don't safe the post there is the post id in the link. If I save it the link is like the titel: projects/postname ...

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do a permalink flush. Go to **Settings -> Permalinks** and then just hit **Save Changes** button. Then try to view again. Should be okay!